# On-demand deployment of war files into Tomcat from a network share?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, war, network-share

I am a newbie to Tomcat; I would like to deploy a war file stored on a network share into a running Tomcat instance. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Tomcat's Manager, in particular, how to [deploy a new application remotely](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Remotely) and how to [reload an existing application](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Reload_An_Existing_Application).

In summary, you'll need to ensure that your WAR is reachable via some sort of URL from the machine running Tomcat. URLs can use http or file scheme.

You mention a network share, so in your particular case you may need to mount the network share so it appears to be a local directory. (Windows URL example follows):

```
file:/X:/path/to/war/
```

You could also try hosting the war file with a web server, and using an http url. (You might already be doing this if you're using a continuous integration server like Bamboo or Hudson.) For example:

```
http://builds.example.com/path/to/war
```